# Inserting a Div Into another Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mootools

Im creating a web app and would like to know why the following code is not working. It first creates a  element which is then added to the body. I then create another Div element which i would like to place inside the first div element that i created.

Im using MooTools classes to create and initialize objects and it works fine but i just cant seem to get the following code to work. The code is inside an`initialize: function()` of a class:

```
this.mainAppDiv = document.createElement("div");
this.mainAppDiv.id = "mainBody";
this.mainAppDiv.style.width = "100%";
this.mainAppDiv.style.height = "80%";
this.mainAppDiv.style.border = "thin red dashed";
document.body.appendChild(this.mainAppDiv); //Inserted the div into <body>
//----------------------------------------------------//
this.mainCanvasDiv = document.createElement("div");
this.mainCanvasDiv.id = "mainCanvas";
this.mainCanvasDiv.style.width = "600px";
this.mainCanvasDiv.style.height = "400px";
this.mainCanvasDiv.style.border = "thin black solid";
document.getElementById(this.mainAppDiv.id).appendChild(this.mainCanvasDiv.id);
```

As you can see it first creates a div called "mainBody" and then appends it the document.body, This part of the code works fine. The problem comes from then creating the second div and trying to insert that using`document.getElementById(this.mainAppDiv.id).i(this.mainCanvasDiv.id);`

Can anyone think of a reason the above code does not work?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in order to insert something into the DOM with a certain ID, you can't just set its id property directly like that - you have to do a `mainAppDiv.setAttribute('id', 'mainBody')`

Answer (score 9):

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById(this.mainAppDiv.id).appendChild(this.mainCanvasDiv.id);
```

Just do:

```
this.mainAppDiv.appendChild(this.mainCanvasDiv);
```

This way you are appending the `mainCanvesDiv` directly to the `mainAppDiv`. There is no need to `getElementById` if you already have a reference to an element.

Answer (score 4):

Do like this:

```
this.mainAppDiv.appendChild(this.mainCanvasDiv);
```

Comment: `this.mainCanvasDiv.id` is not a reference to an the canvas element but its string id

Answer (score 1):

why do you use mootools yet revert to vanilla js?

```
this.mainAppDiv = new Element("div", {
    id: "mainBody",
    styles: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "80%",
        border: "thin red dashed"
    }
});

this.mainCanvasDiv = new Element("div", {
    id: "mainCanvas",
    styles: {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        border: "thin black solid"
    }
}).inject(this.mainAppDiv);

this.mainAppDiv.inject(document.body);
```