# Inserting a div to another div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am inserting a div to another div and I did make it with help of this post
[Inserting a Div Into another Div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525211/inserting-a-div-into-another-div). Here is my code which works fine. 
This function is called by a  element

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="generateDiv(); return false;
"runat="server" 
Text="Create New Group" CausesValidation="False"></asp:LinkButton>

function generateDiv() {
          var grup = document.createElement('div');
          grup.setAttribute('class', 'genDiv');
          grup.setAttribute('id', 'genId');
          this.grp.appendChild(grup);
   }
```

What is the difference between:

```
document.getElementById("#grp").appendChild(grup)
```

and

```
this.grp.appendChild(grup);
```

Comment: how is `generateDiv` called?

Comment: the difference depends on it

Comment: it is called through <linkButton> like this..
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="generateDiv();  return false;" runat="server" 
      Text="Create New Group" CausesValidation="False"></asp:LinkButton>

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("#grp").appendChild(grup).
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> this.grp.appendChild(grup);
> ```

Well, the first will fail, because you don't have any element with the `id` `"#grp"` (you dont' use the `#`, that's the CSS expression for "the next thing is an `id`"). With `document.getElementById`, you don't put in the `#` because it's just expecting an `id`, not a CSS selector, so:

```
document.getElementById("grp").appendChild(grup);
```

About `this`: `this` will be determined by how `generateDiv` is called. **If** it's called as an event handler on the `grp` `div`, then `this` will (probably) already refer to the `grp` element and you don't have to look it up again. If it's called some other way, then `this` is probably something else, and you need to go look up the `grp` `div` via `getElementById`.

**Edit**: From your code you posted later:

> ```
> <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="generateDiv(); return false;" runat="server" Text="Create New Group" CausesValidation="False"></asp:LinkButton>
> ```

...`generateDiv` will see `this` as the global object, and so you have to use `document.getElementById`.

---

Side note: You can, and should, use the reflected properties for both the `class` and `id` attributes:

```
function generateDiv() {
     var grup = document.createElement('div');
     grup.className = 'genDiv';
     grup.id = 'genId';
     document.getElementById("grp").appendChild(grup);
}
```

...not least because IE8 (I think, could be IE7) and below get the `class` one wrong if you use `setAttribute`.

Comment: That's quick nice info, thank you. I was wondering about this in previously asked question, but now it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

html

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

js

```
var e = $('<div></div>');
$('#box').append(e);
```